# Proving the inverse of an elimination matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I am having some trouble proving that the inverse of $M_k = I - m_ke_k^T$ is equal to $L_k  = I + m_ke_k^T$. Where I is an $n x n$ identity matrix, and $M_k$ is the elimination matrix for the $k^{th}$ column $a_k$ of A. I believe I should start by taking the inverse of $M_k$ to get $ (I-m_k e_k^T)^{-1}$, but I am not sure how to expand that result in order to get to $L_k  = I + m_ke_k^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that $e_k^T m_k = 0$.

$(I+m_k e_k^T) (I - m_k e_k^T) = I - m_k e_k^T m_k e_k^T = I$.

Comment: To clarify, is it because by multiplying $M_k$ and $L_k$ you get the back the identity matrix therefore they must be inverses of each other?

Comment: That is how the inverse is defined.

Comment: Could you explain why $e_k^T m_k = 0$ is the case?

Comment: When using the $k$th pivot one has $[m_k]_i = 0$ for $i \le k$. See, for example, Section 3.2.1, the Gauss transformation section of Golub & Van Loan's Matrix Computations.